# Spark dataframe filter vs Hive where clause

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm just wondering if this spark code

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from db.table").filter(col("field")=value)
```

is as efficient as this one:

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from db.table where field=value")
```

In the first bloc are we loading all hive data to the RAM or is spark smart enough to filter those values in hive during the execution of the generated DAG

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its better to get the query plan for both of the approaches. Use .explain().
But Both will have same execution plan I guess. Pls check if its so.

Comment: It gives different parsed logical plans the second one is more optimized  but the final optimized logical plan is the same for the 2, thanks @AbhishekSengupta , I didn't know about this explain function

Comment: welcome, always look for final logical plans , the optimizers in Spark are very intelligent actually. Also try checking the DAG for more information using the Spark UI , usually available at localhost:4040. Make sure you don't close the Session at the end, else you wont be able to check the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether we apply filter through DataFrame functions or Spark SQL on a dataframe or its view , they both will result in same physical plan (it is a plan according to which a spark job is actually executed across a cluster).

The reason behind this is Apache Spark's **Catalyst optimiser**. It is an in-built feature of Spark which turns input SQL queries or DataFrame transformations into a logical and cost optimised physical plan.

You can also have a look at this [databricks link](https://databricks.com/glossary/catalyst-optimizer#:%7E:text=Back%20to%20glossary%20At%20the,build%20an%20extensible%20query%20optimizer.) to understand it more clearly. Further, we can check this physical plan using `.explain` function (**Caution**: `.explain`'s output should be read opposite to conventional way as its last line represents the start of physical plan and first line represents the end of physical plan.)

Answer (score 1):

you dont use same functions, but internaly it's same.

you can use `explain()` to check the logical plan :

```
spark.sql("select * from db.table").filter(col("field")=value).explain()

spark.sql("select * from db.table where field=value").explain()
```

in the first case you use a mixte between spark SQL and Dataset api with the `.filter(col("field")=value)`

in the second case you are pure sql